# How do I split a string by a character, but only when it is not contained within parentheses?

Tags: c#, regex

Input: `((Why,Heck),(Ask,Me),(Bla,No))`

How can I split this data into a string array:

```
  Element1  (Why,Heck)
  Element2  (Ask,Me)
  Element3  (Bla,No)
```

I tried the String.Split or String.TrimEnd/Start but no chance the result is always wrong.

Would it be better with Regex?

Comment: `I tried the String.Split or String.TrimEnd/Start but no chance the result is always wrong.` what have you tried? Why isn't it in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var input = "((Why,Heck),(Ask,Me),(Bla,No))";

var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\([^\(\)]+?\)")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Value)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Tested using this http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx it is correct except for one thing.  It matches the very first parentheses: `((Why,Heck)`

Comment: can you fix the bug where it matches the first parentheses?

Comment: You can simplify: `@"\([^(]+?\)"`.

Comment: Good answer, but just FYI, you don't need to use a reluctant quantifier any more, nor do you have to escape parentheses in a character class.

Comment: @AlanMoore Can you show a sample string what you mean with the reluctant quantifier and the not needed parentheses please?

Comment: @EZI Why do you need the "?" after the "+"? For which case is that? The code works fine when I use only "+" having empty "()" squares or many names in the pair round brackets.

Comment: @Pascal: I was referring to an earlier version of this answer that used the regex `\(.+?\)`.  Since `.` can match parentheses, the reluctant quantifier was necessary to prevent it gobbling up the whole string in one match.  That's not a problem any more, because `[^\(\)]+` can't overrun the closing paren.  To answer your second question, parentheses (like most other metacharacters) lose their special meaning inside a character class, so `[^()]+` works just like `[^\(\)]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Another - non regex approach which should work:

```
string[] result = str.Split(new[]{"),"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
     .Select(s => string.Format("({0})", s.Trim('(', ')')))
     .ToArray();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZcrZSY)

Answer (score 0):

you could also:

1. remove all parenthesis to simplify your splits
2. split by ','
3. Read your returned array in groups of two. That's using a for loop or a similar recursive algorithm, get indices 0 and 1, 2 and 3 e.t.c
4. Reconstruct with parenthesis

Or you could just use Regular expressions